# How to convert this list in a readable format in python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, python-requests

I have the following output stored in a python list and I would like to have it in a readable format; probably in an xml format or csv or json. How do i do that? How do i convert and export the required format.

My code

```
for i in range(1,param_data.shape[0]):
params[i]= dict(param_data.loc[i])
params[i].update(api_dict)
r = requests.get(url, params=params[i])
list1.append(r.content)
```

print (list1)
My output:

```html
[b'<tide>\n<locationdata>\n<nodata info=""/>\n</locationdata>\n</tide>', b'<tide>\n<locationdata>\n<nodata info=""/>\n</locationdata>\n</tide>', b'<tide>\n<locationdata>\n<nodata info=""/>\n</locationdata>\n</tide>', b'<tide>\n<locationdata>\n<nodata info=""/>\n</locationdata>\n</tide>', b'<tide>\n<locationdata>\n<nodata info=""/>\n</locationdata>\n</tide>', b'<tide>\n<locationdata>\n<nodata info=""/>\n</locationdata>\n</tide>', b'<tide>\n<locationdata>\n<location name="KRISTIANSUND" code="KSU" latitude="63.479150" longitude="8.117700" delay="0" factor="1.03" obsname="KRISTIANSUND" obscode="KSU"/>\n<reflevelcode>CD</reflevelcode>\n<data type="prediction" unit="cm">\n<waterlevel value="82.8" time="2017-06-04T16:00:00+01:00" flag="pre"/>\n</data>\n</locationdata>\n</tide>\n', b'<tide>\n<locationdata>\n<nodata info=""/>\n</locationdata>\n</tide>', b'<tide>\n<locationdata>\n<nodata info=""/>\n</locationdata>\n</tide>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That b'string' indicates byte data. You can convert the byte data to string.

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i] = list1[i].decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Comment: superb, I get  the response in different line now, how do I export this list in a text or xml document??

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you first decode the response and convert it to json, then append it into into list.

```
import json
data = json.loads(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
list1.append(data)
```